# AWS service for running a specific Python function

Tags: amazon-web-services

I will have a Flask app that will take some user inputs and run a specific function within my app. I will need a large enough instance as calculated based on the complexity of the user input with an average vCPU number of 36. The CPU usage will be 100 % throughout the function execution as has been tested on a local PC. The Flask app itself will sit on a relatively small instance, probably a t3.micro.

What is the best way to run this app?

Comment: So your Flask app is a kind of scheduler, spinning up the right compute resource to handle a given task? Vanilla EC2 might fit the bill. Launch a custom instance type, give it permissions to access the data it needs (e.g. in S3), and launch it with a userdata script that processes that data. EC2 billing is per second after the first minute. I would want to use SQS, SNS or DynamoDB as a way to manage the state of the launched compute, so your scheduler knows the status of the jobs it has launched. AWS Batch seems overkill. If you need more than a simple step then Step Functions may be valuable.

Comment: How long does your function take to run? How many of these are you expecting per day? Is it okay for users to wait in a queue, or is it more important to get the results back to them quickly (thus running functions in parallel)?